# How to create an IN pin for 5v - 5 pin spdt relay

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, 5v

I have this relay module which has one IN pin, basically that in pin comes from Arduino board , which switches the states of the relay.
[image: 5v Relay Module]

I also have the single relay but they don't have the IN pin.
does any one have the idea how to create the IN pin for single relays on a breadboard.
[image]

Comment: relays pn's have specs for coil current that probably exceed Arduino outputs, which is why the board has transistors. If you had logic level FETs, you can search how to do

Comment: That board has **two** IN pins (IN1,IN2) which drives Q1 and Q2 which in turn switches the relay coils.

Comment: Guys , i have very poor knowledge in electronics, can u give me more simple answer, how to achieve such in pin with the single relays. what more parts do i need to connect to, and how will be the connections.

Answer (score 1):

You have an Opto-Isolated 2 Channel Relay Board

Look at the schematic and find the two IN pins for activating the optocoupler, followed by driving Q1 and Q2 (2 channels) resulting in  driving the relays.
The IN pins should be connected to output pins from the Arduino
The Q3 in the picture should be Q2.
The supply voltage (VCC) comes also from Arduino and if you have enough power they can be combined. This has already be done in your picture.
If you do not have enough power from the Arduino you should separate the VCC and have a separate supply for the relay driving transistors and relays.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer , thanks for answering in details sir . The same Voltage source i can use , its sufficient for my project.
Due to poor knowledge in electronics i am not be able to understand fully what is going on. 
I request you to give me one more simple answer. Like Which parts shall i use and how to connect them. Do i need to buy the optocoupler ? and what other things i need ??
What ever i have googled for such relays is , they work on NO/NC states , that state i want to control using IN pin like the first Opto-Isolated 2 Channel Relay Board picture i have posted.